# Map 3 list to a single list in python

Tags: python

Suppose i have 3 lists

```
[1,2,3]
['one','two','three']
['first','second','third']
```

I need to combine this into a single list like

```
[[1,'one','first'],[2,'two','second','third'],[3,'three','third']]
```

How do we do this?Using list comprehension?Is there any other best method?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip`

```
>>>list(zip([1,2,3],['one','two','three'],['first','second','third']))
[(1, 'one', 'first'), (2, 'two', 'second'), (3, 'three', 'third')]
```

or as list of lists

```
>>>list(map(list, zip([1,2,3],['one','two','three'],['first','second','third'])))
[[1, 'one', 'first'], [2, 'two', 'second'], [3, 'three', 'third']]
```

Note: The outermost `list` call exists only to provide immediate evaluation of the `map`/`zip` functions and are not required if you will iterate over them later.